Is it possible to design an apparatus that implements a software invention without infringing on the method or system claims?
Let's take Tinder's swipe patent as an example: US11513666B2
https://patents.google.com/patent/US11513666B2/en?oq=US11513666B2
If the patent only contains claims for method and system, is it really possible for someone to design an apparatus that implements the software invention without infringing on the system or method claims?
If that is not possible, then would it be a waste of resources, e.g. attorney fees and time, to include an apparatus claim for a software invention?

If you add a link to the patent, you make it more convenient for others to answer your question.

done. but I am wondering if this question can be answered a priori.

What do you think differentiates a system claim from an apparatus claim ? Neither is the name of a statutorily defined category of invention/claim.

The four statutory classes are:

Process, Machine, Manufacture, Composition of Matter

The last of these is not relevant to software inventions. Software inventions can be seen as being processes that are carried out by computers, or as machines that include at least one computer plus appropriate programming, or as articles of manufacture that are storage media containing instructions that can be interpreted by a computer.
With the ubiquity of downloading software from the Internet, storage medium claims have fallen out of currency. Unfortunately it is not possible to claim a signal that would encode a particular software unless it is "non-transitory". This excludes most forms of Internet that are based on transitory signals propagating through copper, optical fiber, or wirelessly.
Interesting fact, some parts of a "system" (and probably also machine/apparatus) may be located physically outside the U.S. but the whole may still infringe:
https://www.mintz.com/sites/default/files/media/documents/2018-10-08/IVCJ%20Extraterritorial%20reach%20of%20US%20patent%20laws.pdf

An interesting and informative answer. It would be improved by explicitly addressing the question.

@EricS I agree. From what I gather, the answer is saying that both an apparatus and a system is a machine, so therefore there is no difference? But I have seen patents that claim both an apparatus and a system.

I don't think there is much difference between apparatus and system in most cases, but I wouldn't want to make sweeping statements about that because the meaning is influenced by the content of the specification in question. Claiming both sounds dodgy to me unless the specification has guidance differentiating them and making clear what the difference in scope is. Examiners are supposed to object to duplicate or subtly reworded claims when there is no clear difference in scope (MPEP 608.01(M)).
